# New Menu Options Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, new-experience

I'm not sure what happened to one of our Home pages, but it is now missing all the options under "New". This menu is now acting like a sub page. What can I do to get them back? Is there a specific layout that only allows these New Options?

[image]

[image]

I find it very strange you can only access these options through a Home page. We have no way to create a new "Plan".

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with Page. I was testing in my environment, and I used both modern team site and communications sites. I create a new page using UI and make it as home page, and it displays all the links like first image you posted. This has something to do with Command Bar itself. Do you remember changing any thing which cause this issue?

Comment: What happened is we migrated another Home.aspx that we wanted to copy. It was using the same communication template but ShareGate must have change something in the background.

Comment: Do you have access to PnP PowerShell on site? Can you get the output of following code (remove <br/> with new line)?

Comment: $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Login to SPO"<br/>
Connect-PnPOnline https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_coll> -Credentials $cred<br/>

$page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Home.aspx"<br/>
$page.LayoutType<br/>

Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Home.aspx" -LayoutType Home<br/>

Comment: There are a couple errors in that script, I can't rejig it to work. If you want to start an answer it would be easier to read

Comment: Following is the main line I want you to execute. It will reset the page to OOB home page. You might have to add all webpart back to page.

Comment: `Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "Home.aspx" -LayoutType Home`

Comment: The actual scripts look like this, https://gist.github.com/thinkb4code/d33e1c65628918af0dc465e4f32a7ba1.

Comment: The code runs but doesn't affect Home.aspx. Nothing changes including the New menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99411/discussion-between-thinkb4code-and-michael-colbs).

Answer (score 0):

I think the home page of the site could be changed by someone. By design, these New Options only could be shown in site home page.

Try to make this page Home.aspx homepage, check whether if it works.
[image]

Comment: It is the homepage, I already tried that but the menu remains